# some trouble on how to sum elements on a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, sum, equals

My problem is that for example i have this list on prolog

[[1,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,1],[3,1]]

I want as result:
[1,2],[2,4],[3,1]

in short word if the first element of the lists is equal i want to sum the second elements of that lists,

and return a list with that same element on the first position and the sum of the second elements as the second element of the list.

I fint easy doing this on something like python but in prolog i can't figure a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive visit seems the easiest way to me:

```
sum_keys([], []).
sum_keys([[K,V]|L], U) :-
    sum_keys(L, S),
    (   select([K,C], S, T),
        N is V+C,
        U = [[K,N]|T]
    ;   U = [[K,V]|S]
    ).
```

This yields

```
?- sum_keys([[1,1],[1,1],[2,1],[2,2],[2,1],[3,1]],R),sort(R,S).
R = S, S = [[1, 2], [2, 4], [3, 1]] .
```

Note that the pair representation is not optimal: in Prolog we usually adopt `Key-Value`, then we can access some [library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.18%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pairs.html%27%29%29), and write

```
:- [library(pairs)].

list2pair([K,V], K-V).
sum_value_list(K-L, K-S) :- sumlist(L,S).

sum_keys(L, S) :-
    maplist(list2pair, L, Ps),
    group_pairs_by_key(Ps, Grouped),
    maplist(sum_value_list, Grouped, Summed),
    maplist(list2pair, S, Summed).
```

Of course, list2pair conversions are due to the representation mismatch .